# Show only predefined value in axes MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, axes, subplot

I would like to only show these `x-values` on the `x-axes`

```
 xx=[0.0005 0.005 0.05 0.1 0.25 0.5 0.75 1 1.25 1.5];
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Hi @AliBodaghi , take a look at http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/creating_plots/individual-axis-control.html You will find an aswer to your question and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify axis labels using [XtTickLabel](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html) property. For example:

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',[0.0005 0.005 0.05 0.1 0.25 0.5 0.75 1 1.25 1.5])
```

This will change only labels, not actual values on the plot. To check values as well you can use:

```
set(gca,'XTick',[0.0005 0.005 0.05 0.1 0.25 0.5 0.75 1 1.25 1.5]);
set(gca,'XScale','log');  % Your xx values seem to be logarithmic, so this can help.
```

Comment: I have a problem when it is run for more than one figure. Let's say it is works for figure,
set(gca,'XTickLabel',[64 128 256 512])
plot([64 128 256 512],[ber_LPC_SVD(1) ber_LPC_SVD(2) ber_LPC_SVD(3) ber_LPC_SVD(4)],'r') but it does not work for xx=[64 128 256 512];
figure,
set(gca,'XTickLabel',[64 128 256 512])
hold on
plot(xx,ber_LPC_SVD(:),'r')
plot(xx,ber_LWT_SVD(:),'b')
plot(xx,ber_DWT_SVD(:),'k')
plot(xx,ber_QIM_SVD(:),'y')
plot(xx,ber_LPC_DCT(:),'g')
xlabel('Frame length (sample)'), ylabel('BER (%)')
hold off why ?